# How can I get the tap Pose in ARCore?

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, camera, arcore

I can't figure out how to get the exact camera Pose in ARCore. Until now, I placed a 3D object roughly at the camera world position. Then I update its model matrix to make it slowly move towards its Anchor Pose on the tapped plane.

The issue is it places the object not always at the camera pose, how can I fix this?

(I'm on AndroidStudio working with ARCore)

Comment: If you mean place the object in front of the camera, this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56681538/334402

Comment: The Anchor code was helpful, thank you. Anyway, I need something different: place the anchor on a plane then translate the object to the camera pose. This way I can update its model matrix to let it drift towards that plane, in the following frames. Plus, I'm not working with SceneView, only ARCore